# Can QImage::operator== return false for images with the same contents

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

The docs seem ambiguous. Do they mean that that it returns true if each pixel of the images contents is the same, even if the image has different encoding? What do they mean when they say "different format" - what if only the format is different, but width/height is the same, and the pixels have the same ARGB values?

From the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#operator-eq):

> bool QImage::operator== ( const QImage & image ) const
>
> Returns true if this image and the given image have the same contents;
>   otherwise returns false. The comparison can be slow, unless there is
>   some obvious difference (e.g. different size or format), in which case
>   the function will return quickly.

Comment: Look at the source here (line 4897): https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/61570cd378e1b5a257ad90efcdac4098cb85262c:src/gui/image/qimage.cpp It clearly returns false if either the size or the formats differ.

Answer (score 1):

They mean that the first thing that is checked is size and format, and if they are different, the function immediately returns `false` since it's obvious that the images are different - that is why the function will return quickly since no pixels will be compared, and that is the pixels comparison that takes the most time. They are clear that size OR format must be different in order for the function to return 'quickly' (i.e. to immediately know that the images are different).

It's not really possible that, except for the format, two images would have the same ARGB values, because it is the format that defines pixel values - many formats don't have the 'A' channel, some formats invert the order of channels (e.g. RGBA); there are formats that don't have anything close to ARGB at all (e.g. Format_Mono). Take a look at `enum QImage::Format` in the docs, and you will get the idea.

Pictures having different formats have different memory sizes and totally different pixel values that you cannot even compare in any way (because there is no standard way to compare e.g. 24 bit pixel and 16 bit pixel, even if they are both RGB); they also cannot look exactly the same - that is why people invented so many different format to suit different needs. Format defines what it means that a pixel has a certain value, so it also determines the look.

**So, to sum it up briefly:** if dimensions or format of two images are different, you can already say at this stage that these images don't have the same contents, so it is enough information for the == operator to return false.

Comment: So does that mean it can return false if the images would look the same when displayed (same alpha channel values as well, of course)?

Comment: `So does that mean it can return false if the images would look the same` An imaging library doesn't have eyes.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie By "look the same" I mean having the same values, regardless of the bit-packing, kind of like how the text inside of a text file can be the same regardless of whether it uses UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoding. And it wouldn't need to "have eyes" for that, same is for images. To put it that way, convertToARGB32Format(img1) == convertToARGB32Format(img2), will img1 == img2 return false?

Comment: @sashoalm, with images it's different because you don't apply different encoding to the same image, but in order to open the image in different format, you have to convert it, i.e. change original information, which involves inter/extrapolating values, rounding or truncating them etc. You can view text as UTF-8 or UTF-16 and the text itself remains unchanged, but you cannot view an image in different format without changing it. If you have one input image, convert it to two different formats, and then convert them to the same format again, they will not be the same.

Comment: They will differ, because they will lose/change some information during conversion.

Comment: @user3564091 Not if you upscale the format - converting from 1-bit monochrome pixmap to 32-bit ARGB will not lose information. That's why I used convertToARGB32Format() - it contains the maximum information of all Qt image formats, so no info can be lost when converting to it.

Comment: @sashoalm, did you check that it actually works, or do you speculate?